# IBOutlet for NSTextField in NSTitlebarAccessoryView

Tags: swift, cocoa, desktop-application, iboutlet, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

In my document based application, I have added a Label (`NSTextField`) to my document's window's titlebar using the new API for 10.10 :

I call this from my main `NSViewController` that I have controlling the main view that comes with the window for free :

```
class MasterViewControler: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        window.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(TitleBarSubviewControler(nibName: "TitleBarSubview", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())!)
    }
```

So that loads the custom view containing my label into my titlebar as the docs suggest. All good so far.

Now at some point I must access that label at runtime to change it's string value, from somewhere within my app.

I tried adding an `IBOutlet` for the label to the `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` that controls the subview, and as expected from the `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` I can manipulate the labels `stringValue`. But I can't do much from there.

I tried creating a function in the  `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` that sets the label string, and accessing that function via a global instance of the `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController()` from my `mainViewControler`, but although I can access this function and pass it a string, the reference the the labels `IBOutlet` in the function always unwraps as nil (crash).

So why is the outlet unwrapping as nil in the function when access from anywhere but inside the class where the function resides.?

I must be able to access the label from a controller or view within my windows `mainView`.

How can I do this..?

[image: My Possible Structure]

Comment: Please see my best effort in my answer below. I do not think it's great at all.

Answer (score 0):

I could not for the life of me find a way to reference the label in the subview I added to the windows titlebar via IB, so the best workaround I can find is this :

```
class WindowControler: NSWindowController {

    var titlebarLabel:NSTextField?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        // add the titlebar subview
        window?.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(TitlebarSubviewControler(nibName: "TitlebarSubview", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())!)
        // get reference to the titlibarLabel I just added in the line above
        var subviewsOfTheLastTitleBarView: AnyObject? = window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)?.superview?.subviews.last?.subviews[0]
        var titlebarNSTextField: AnyObject? = subviewsOfTheLastTitleBarView?.subviews[0]
        titlebarLabel = (titlebarNSTextField! as NSTextField)
    }

    @IBAction func tempbuttonclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        titlebarLabel?.stringValue = "Text seen in titlebar subview"
    }

}
```

So I am hunting through the titlebar here, to find the NSTextField right after I add it to the titlebar in the first line of windowDidLoad, and taking a lot for granted.

I am pretty worried this could break very easily, just not sure about doing it like this. Any better solutions greatly appreciated.